# packages not installing - "Error: tunneling socket could not be established"

Tags: npm

Debian squeeze (Internet connection running through Tor), nodejs built from the current source - the error has only just started occuring:

```
root@...# npm install coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm ERR! Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket hang up
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.onError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/tunnel.js:161:17)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:193:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1330:9)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.exports.connect.cleartext._controlReleased (tls.js:1298:15)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.error (tls.js:952:10)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream._done (tls.js:432:17)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream._pull (tls.js:577:12)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-3-486
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "coffee-script"
npm ERR! cwd /home/...
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.11
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.62
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! 
...
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Iceweasel is also showing an invalid security certificate error for  https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script.

Anyone any idea what is missing here?  (It has occured in the past, fixed itself though for some odd reason.)

Answer (score 3):

Tried setting `ca` and `strict-ssl` config options (null and false resp.), didn't work, however setting the `registry` config option to http://registry.npmjs.org/ and packages are installing again - should this be an ssl domain then?

Comment: Just ran into the same issue. Why is the default not working on Mac OS X Mavericks, but it works on Windows 7 ?